# Localize date time column

Tags: python, pandas

The purpose of this code is to read a csv file which has a column called “DateTime”.

The dates on this column based an “EST” time zone which is not mine so the code must localize the date time column to my system time zone.

When I tried this code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
from tzlocal import get_localzone

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Sayed\Desktop\script\data.csv")
print(df)
format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z"
for date in df['DateTime']:
    date = datetime(timezone('EST'))
    now_local = date.astimezone(get_localzone())
    print(now_local.strftime(format))
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:/Projects/Tutorial/ff.py", line 10, in <module>
    date = datetime(timezone('EST'))

TypeError: an integer is required (got type EST)
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `DateTime` column is already of `datetime` type, **you can try to use [tz_localize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tz_localize.html) with [tz_convert](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.tz_convert.html) functions**.

Replace you `for` loop with this:

```
df['DateTime'] = df['DateTime'].dt.tz_localize('EST').dt.tz_convert(get_localzone())
```

After this your `DateTime` column should have a datetime in your local timezone.